# Changing processor architecture with node-gyp configure

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-gyp

I am trying to create a Node C Addon. Mine is a 64bit machine but I need to compile the Node C Addon as a 32 bit binary. By default, node-gyp picks up all the 64 bit libraries for compilation and linking process.

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "cflags": [ "-m32" ],
      "ldflags": [ "-m elf_i386" ],
      "cflags_cc": [ "-fPIC -m32" ],
      "target_name": "hello",
      "sources": [ "Hello.cpp" ],
    }
}
```

This is my bindings.gyp file. I am passing `-m32` in cflags and setting `ldflags` as `-m elf_i386`. It compiles fine but I still see `-m64` as well in the verbose output of compilation process.

```
g++ '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' ... 
-fPIC -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -pthread -m64 -m32 -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing 
-fno-tree-vrp -fno-tree-sink -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fPIC -MMD -MF 
./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/hello/Hello.o.d.raw  -c -o 
Release/obj.target/hello/Hello.o ../Hello.cpp
```

And It still tries to find 64 bit libraries during the linking process and fails.

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-****/4.1.2/libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

That incompatible file is actually a soft link to `/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8`

I compile with `node-gyp clean configure build --verbose`

How can I override this behaviour and make node-gyp compile for 32 bit architecture?

Comment: `node-gyp` builds addons for the current system/installation of `node`. Why do you need to build 32-bit when using 64-bit? If you're hoping to distribute precompiled binaries, NPM doesn't currently offer support.

Comment: But I can ship all my cpp files as part of the package and compile them during the install time, right?

Comment: Yeah. NPM will default `{ "scripts": { "install": ... } }` in the `package.json` [to `"node-gype rebuild"`](https://github.com/isaacs/read-package-json/blob/v1.1.0/read-json.js#L128-L146) in projects with files matching `*.gyp`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally figured out a way to do this.

```
node-gyp clean configure build --verbose --arch=ia32
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the option as a gyp file directive? Because that would save the user a bit of time.

Comment: It also looks like it's only the configuration step that needs to be aware of the system's architecture.

Comment: Is there an exhaustive list for the --arch values? Where did you find the value you used?